Peppa pig and purple rabbit?
My son goes on and on about a Peppa pig episode where there are purple rabbit(s) or rabbit-like animals. But I can't find it. It might be that they use paint or masks. He might be wrong also.
Most likely seasons 1-4

Peppa and the gang wear masks in the prosaically-titled episode "Masks". Peppa's mask is purple.



